# Is it possible to make two layouts share one ImageView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I mean how can i locate a ImageView in two layouts? i have 2 relative layouts one is up, one is down. The up one has a ImageView but i want half of this ImageView located in down layout. How can i do that?

EDIT::

[image: I want something like this]

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Maybe a drawing of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: What was your xml?

Comment: You can't really span an image outside of its current layout.  You should wrap your existing layouts in a parent.  I did answer what you are asking.

Comment: I upload a picture. you can see it in my edit.

Comment: Check my answer, i am sure it will be work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:background="#d2aff4">

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/center"
        android:background="#87c96d" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In this scenario the "top" layout needs to be created at last to be displayed on top of the rest of the views. If you need it to have a background colour, you need to apply the colour to the main container.

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Still don't know why your ImageView must be child of your top layout, the other answers are valid.

Comment: Thanks for answer. it helped.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [@Booger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/636988/booger) answer's but If your parent layout is `RelativeLayout` then add this below property in you `ImageView`.

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Or you can use below code to create that kind of layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/gray_font">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent">

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but imageview must be child of uplayout.

Comment: @Onur ... **why**? You know, it **can't** be.

Comment: I thinks it's the best approach if you want the RelativeLayouts to take half of the screen. Dunno if it can be simplify using a ConstraintLayout?

Comment: @KlingKlang Yes i know but i just wanted to make sure of it. maybe there is a way to do it but apparently there is not.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this library https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

if you want something easy you can put those layouts in to a parent relative layout and then you can add a image view in parent relative layout as last child and position it how you need

Comment: Caution when using RelativeLayout as a Parent!  This will cause too many measure cycles (better to use a LinearLayout)

Comment: But if you use linear layout as parent, you can not add an image view on other layouts. As you know other views in linear layout must be in an vertical or horizontal order.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wrap both your RelativeLayout in another Parent layout, and in that layout, you will place your ImageView (which will span both the other layouts.

Something like this pseudo-code:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout1>
    <RelativeLayout2>
    <ImageView gravity=center> //Order counts, this needs to be after the RelativeLayouts to show on top of them
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but imageview must be child of relativelayout1.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible, you can not span a view outside of its parent container.

Comment: Doesn't work as children in a LinearLayout are piled, so you can't centre one of them in the parent.